# derived from streambuf, ostream and manip - not compile or crashed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So, I started an indenting buffer/ostream,setting the indent level using manipulators and run into problems... The first was the compiler error
`indent_ostream& increase(indent_ostream&)' will always evaluate as 'true'`. Just made a operator<< for function pointers as member of the ostream. The next than was `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'indent_ostream' and 'int')`. Also added a member operator<< with templated argument to catch all types to be streamed (string, int, etc).This results into an `Segmentation fault` and here I am :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iomanip>

class indent_sbuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf*     m_sbuf;
    std::string         m_indent_str;
    bool                m_start_of_line;
    static const int    TAB_WIDTH = 4;

public:
    explicit indent_sbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf, size_t indent = 0)
        : m_sbuf{ sbuf }
        , m_indent_str(indent, ' ')
        , m_start_of_line{ true }
    { }

    ~indent_sbuf()
    {
        overflow('\n');
    }

    indent_sbuf& increase()
    {
        m_indent_str = std::string(m_indent_str.size() + TAB_WIDTH, ' ');
        return *this;
    }

    indent_sbuf& decrease()
    {
        if(m_indent_str.size() > TAB_WIDTH) {
            m_indent_str = std::string(m_indent_str.size() - TAB_WIDTH, ' ');
        }
        else {
            m_indent_str = "";
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int_type overflow(int_type chr) override
    {
        if (m_start_of_line && chr != '\n') {
            m_sbuf->sputn( m_indent_str.data(), m_indent_str.size() );
        }
        m_start_of_line = (chr == '\n');
        return m_sbuf->sputc( chr );
    }
};

class indent_ostream : public std::ostream
{
    indent_sbuf buf;

public:
    indent_ostream(std::ostream& os, size_t width)
        : std::ostream(&buf)
        , buf(os.rdbuf(), width)
    { }

    indent_ostream& operator<<(indent_ostream& (*fcn)(indent_ostream&))
    {
        return (*fcn)(*this);
    }

    template<typename T>
    indent_ostream& operator<<(T const& v) // get it to compile
    {
        *this << v; // but crash
        return *this;
    }
};

static inline
indent_ostream& increase(indent_ostream& os)
{
    indent_sbuf* buf = static_cast<indent_sbuf*>(os.rdbuf());
    buf->increase();
    return os;
}

static inline
indent_ostream& decrease(indent_ostream& os)
{
    indent_sbuf* buf = static_cast<indent_sbuf*>(os.rdbuf());
    buf->decrease();
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    indent_ostream os(std::cout, 0);
    os << "Hallo\n";
    os << increase << "World\n";
    os << decrease << 42 << "\n";
}
```

Also at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4763401d424c051f). So, what going on here and where are my faults? How to get it working correct and standard conforming?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: if you get a warning you don't understand, don't hammer away at your code to make it go away. Try to understand the warning.

Comment: ^ you can remove a compiler warning by fixing the problem the compiler's detecting, or by making detection of the problem too difficult for the compiler to reasonably do so. Hammering away at the code until it 'works' is rather more likely to lead to the second, than if you try to understand it first.

Comment: some people are forejudge here, maybe my fault due to the style of writing the way to come into the problem....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you got a warning:

> The first was the compiler error `indent_ostream& increase(indent_ostream&)'` will always evaluate as 'true'

Why? What does that mean? What does `os << increase` actually do? Don't just ignore the warning! It is pointing out that you have a real problem in your code! Investigate!

If you look in the list of operators for [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), there is this one:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

but that one doesn't match your function, it's not a viable candidate. The function `Derived&(*)(Derived&)` is not a match for `Base&(*)(Base&)` - it can never work. Instead, the best (only) viable candidate is:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );
```

Because function pointers are convertible to `bool`. The warning is that this is silly, because obviously this will print `1` and is probably not what you intended to do.

But you don't actually *need* the function to take an `indent_ostream` anyway. All you care about is the buffer. So the solution is to fix your modifiers to match the expected signature:

```
static inline std::ostream& increase(std::ostream& os)
{
    indent_sbuf* buf = static_cast<indent_sbuf*>(os.rdbuf());
    buf->increase();
    return os;
}

static inline std::ostream& decrease(std::ostream& os)
{
    indent_sbuf* buf = static_cast<indent_sbuf*>(os.rdbuf());
    buf->decrease();
    return os;
}
```

And now, it works!

Comment: To clarify: I didn't ignored the warning. But my conclusions where different and false. Quick search got the point to boolean convertible too. Josutties Std C++ Lib book section "How manipulators work" showed the operator<<(...(*op)(..)) overload. Hence my thoughs where this must be missing. Wrong conclusion ... The reason why I wrote increase(indent_ostream&..) was to avoid hijacking the std::ostream since the underlaying buffer hasn't an increase member function. This way the miracle started.

Comment: Anyway, good explanations, but I still not understand why the Segmentation fault - took the operator<<(T const&) the manipulator even that (imo) operator<<(indent_ostream&..) is more viable?

Comment: @Olx Well... at what point are you putting your override of `streambuf` into `cout`?

Comment: at the point where I use template argument for the ostream, once using the std::ostream directly and not the indent_ostream. I assumed I have to overload the increase/decrease (std::ostream&) with 'empty' dummys than.

Comment: @Olx What function do you think `*this << v;` calls?

Comment: after even more thinking about: I would say the same member function - which results into stack overflow due to recursive call, isn't it?